# Since the rest of the division of an integer b by 7 is 5, calculate the remainder of the division by 7 of the following numbers.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

a) $-b$

b) $2b$

c) $3b + 7$

d) $10b + 1$

e) $b^2 + b + 1$

I solved the first 3 only, But the way I solved is too much work.

I solved by drawing a clock with (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

**a)** I ran in the anticlockwise 5 times from 0, and I got 2.

**b)** This time i run in the clockwise direction, as b leaves 5 as remainder, I ran 5 times from 5, to get 3.

**c)** I did the same as b, and I got 1

Is there a way to solve these questions fast ? In more complex problems It would take much time to solve that way I did.

Comment: set $$b=5+7m$$ where $m$ is an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $b=7k+5$,

1) $(-7k-5)\bmod7=-5\bmod7=2.$

2) $(14k+10)\bmod7=10\bmod7=3.$

3) $(21k+22)\bmod7=22\bmod7=1.$

4) $(70k+51)\bmod7=51\bmod7=2.$

5) $(49k^2+77k+31)\bmod7=31\bmod7=3.$

---

**Faster**:

In all cases, $f(b)\bmod7=f(b\bmod7)$, as the expressions are polynomials of integer coefficients.

Then

1) $-5\bmod7=2.$

2) $(2\cdot5)\bmod7=3.$

3) $(3\cdot5+3)\bmod7=1.$

4) $(10\cdot5+1)\bmod7=2.$

5) $(5^2+5+1)\bmod7=3.$

Comment: thanks for this amazing answer.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$b\equiv 5 \mod 7$$
$$\implies$$
$$ -b \equiv -5 \equiv 2 (7) $$

$$2b\equiv 10 \equiv 3 (7) $$

$$3b+7\equiv 3b\equiv 15\equiv 1 (7) $$

You can take the rest.